# Many to Many single query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables with many to many relation

```
 CREATE TABLE news(id int, content varchar(64));
CREATE TABLE tags(id int, name varchar(64));
CREATE TABLE news_tags(id int, tag_id int, news_id int);

INSERT INTO news VALUES
(1, "Hello, world!"),
(2, "Test news"),
(3, "test news 2"),
(4, "test news 3"),
(5, "test news 4");

INSERT INTO tags VALUES
(1, "general tag"),
(2, "sub tag 1"),
(3, "sub tag 2"),
(4, "normal tag");

INSERT INTO news_tags VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1);


INSERT INTO news_tags VALUES
(4, 1, 2),
(5, 2, 2),

(6, 1, 3),
(7, 4, 3),

(7, 2, 4),
(8, 3, 4),

(9, 1, 5);
```

I want to select news_id what

1. On relation have only general (id 1 on example) tag and dont have any other sub tag (on exmpl id 3)
2. Have pair of tags general + sub tag (id 2)

I create a query

```
SELECT news_id FROM news_tags WHERE tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 2 
    GROUP BY news_id 
    HAVING COUNT(news_id) = 2
UNION
SELECT news_id FROM news_tags WHERE tag_id = 1 AND news_id not in (SELECT news_id FROM news_tags WHERE tag_id in (2,3));
```

but have 2 problems

1. I think its not optimization way (have 2 select with union + sub select query)
2. if i what search more one pairs sub tags i need add new select with union

How can i optimizate this query ?

live example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1067b7/1/0

Comment: can you give your expected results based on your fiddle?

Comment: @18Man on fiddle is right results

Comment: The concept of 'sub tag' is not clear, and from what you show as expected result, it is hard to make sense of it. Cannot optimise without knowing what you want to do achieve. Also, your news_tags must use a 'composite key' (not an extra id field), and all your tables must have at least primary keys (aka indexes).

Comment: @geertjanvdk for example you have some news with some tags, and now you need block some news for some countries , the fast way to do this add some tags like tag "block" its meen to block news for search for all country or add tags "block" "usa" its meen to block news only form usa country but not for other country its clear explanation ?

Comment: @geertjanvdk so when you serach news by country , you need get news for news_ids not in (ids)
ids - contains news_ids what accept 2 conditions 
1) news on news_tags table have "block" tag and dont have other country tag (block for all countries)
2)  news on news_tags table have  "block" and "country tag" (block for search country)

Comment: needs full table schemas and current execution plan, I'd think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like i found solution without made change on schema tables

```
SELECT news_id, tag_id
FROM news_tags
WHERE tag_id in (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY news_id 
HAVING (COUNT(news_id) = 1 AND tag_id = 1) OR (count(news_id) = 2 and tag_id in (1,2));
```

first we find all news with blocked tags , than with HAVING filter result

```
(COUNT(news_id) = 1 AND tag_id = 1)
```

find all record with only "blocked" tag for all countrys (its part can use for on many to many find all records what use only single tag)

```
(count(news_id) = 2 and tag_id in (1,2))
```

find pairs of "blocked" tag and country tag

if we need more country we need add OR and

```
(count(news_id) = 2 and tag_id in (1,3))
```

i need do some test but look like its work nice , and better that my first query

Comment: What if tag number 4 comes along? Are you going to dynamically create the SQL query each time in your application? If so, I would seriously reconsider using a relational database for this. If it is a homework assignment it would be okish (would fail in my class).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear because the concepts of "sub" tags and "general" tags are not defined.

But if you want to handle multiple conditions at the same time, you can still use one `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

For instance, if you wanted `news_id`s that met either of these conditions:

- `tag_id` = 1
- Or both `tag_id` = 2 and `tag_id` = 3

Then you can use:

```
SELECT nt.news_id
FROM news_tags nt
GROUP BY nt.news_id 
HAVING (COUNT(*) = 1 AND MIN(nt.tag_id) = 1) OR
       SUM( nt.tag_id IN (2, 3) ) = 2;
```

You can easily extend this idea to the descriptions of the tags (but you need to join in the `tags` table for that.

Comment: >Your question is unclear because the concepts of "sub" tags and "general" tags are not defined.

for example you have some news with some tags, and now you need block some news for some countries , the fast way to do this add some tags like tag "block" its meen to block news for search for all country or add tags "block" "usa" its meen to block news only form usa country but not for other country its clear explanation ?

Comment: your query select news what have tags "block" or country tags ("usa", "can").

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest based on the extra comments about blocking tags, to do a redesign.

Assigning tags to news items is good, but your table should look like `news_tags(news_id, tag_id)`, and primary key is over both `news_id`, and `tag_id` field.

If you want to make tags blocking, one way is to add another Many-To-Many relation, called `news_blocking_tags(news_id, tag_id)`. Or you can define your `news_tags(news_id, tag_id, is_blocking)`, so you know which tags are blocking, and which are just tags.

Optimising starts with designing the database. We can only give general pointers here. Good that you know what the outcome needs to be, that's already half the design!

Comment: look please my solution 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65973321/2420249

Answer (score 0):

I've done tagging many times.  I recommend *not* using a many-to-many mapping table to a tag table.  Instead, combine them into

```
 CREATE TABLE tags (
     news_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- Assuming you don't need more than 16M
     tag VARCHAR(...) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(news_id, tag),  -- For going one way
     INDEX(tag, news_id)         -- For going the other way
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;    -- Important due to the way indexes are handled
```

Adding an auto_inc is a waste of space and speed.

Yeah, some queries get a big gnarly.  But any technique leads to messy code; I belive that this schema is the best.